Question on $L^2$-harmonic forms
Let $(M,g)$ be a non-compact complete Riemannian manifold. In the following, I denote by $\Omega^{k}(M)$ the set of smooth $k$-forms and by $L^{2}_{k}(M)$ the set of $L^{2}$ $k$-forms, i.e.
$$L^{2}_{k}(M):=\overline{\Omega^{k}_{c}(M)}^{\Vert\cdot\Vert_{L^{2}}}$$
where $\Vert\cdot\Vert_{L^{2}}$ is the usual Hodge $L^{2}$-inner product. Now, in many places, one can find the following claim:

A $L^{2}$-form $\omega$ is harmonic, i.e. $\Delta\omega=0$, if and only if $d\omega=\delta\omega=0$.

Here, $\Delta=d\delta+\delta d$ denotes the Hodge Laplacian. By elliptic regularity, any $\omega$ satisfying either $\Delta\omega=0$ or $(d+\delta)\omega=0$ is smooth and hence, the expressions above are well-defined. Now, the idea of the proof is quite simple: We would like to write
$$\langle\omega,\Delta\omega\rangle_{L^{2}}=\Vert d\omega\Vert_{L^{2}}^{2}+\Vert\delta\omega\Vert_{L^{2}}^{2}$$
because then the claim is obvious. However, for this to be true, we need a $L^{2}$-Stokes theorem, which allows us to do something like $\langle\alpha,d\beta\rangle_{L^{2}}=\langle\delta\alpha,\beta\rangle_{L^{2}}$. As it turns out, such a $L^{2}$-Stokes theorem does in fact hold for complete manifolds. However, if I look in the original references like (Gaffney 1954), they usually need some more requirements. More precisely, it seems to me that for the above Theorem to be true, one also needs to assume that $d\omega\in L^{2}$ and $\delta\omega\in L^{2}$. However, this is usually not stated (see for example this notes here). So, how does the proof avoid this requirements? Does $\Delta\omega=0$ somehow imply that both $d\omega$ and $\delta\omega$ are in $L^{2}$?

[I would have just commented but I am new here so I do not have reputation.]
I did not read the whole notes, however the author mentions "maximal domains", which is indeed what the traditional texts demand i.e. $\mathcal{D}^k(M) = \{\omega\in L^2| d\omega\in L^2\}$. Else the statement $(\alpha,d \beta)_{L^2} = (\delta\alpha,\beta)_{L^2}$ could not possibly be true, because the expressions would not even be defined (if $d\omega\notin L^2$ you cannot take its scalar product in $L^2$ by definition).

Yes, I am aware of that. But, in the context of the statement "$\omega\in L^{2}$ is harmonic if and only if $d\omega=\delta\omega=0$", one usually does not assume that  $d\omega,\delta\omega\in L^{2}$ on the left hand side. In this is the point that confuses me.

If $\omega$ is (Hodge)-harmonic its Hodge Laplacian vanishes. By elliptic regularity $\omega$ has to be in EVERY Sobolev space... and if $\delta\omega = 0$ and $ d\omega = 0$ then $\omega$ will certainly be harmonic. This follows from Gardings inequality in the compact / bounded case. However, I am not sure if it holds true in the general case... Maybe look for a more general form of Gardings ineqaulity...
